# Algorithm to match Suitability Criteria

Tags: angularjs

I'm building an application to see how suitable an applicant is for a certain vacancy.

Essentially, an HR Executive will define the required skills/qualifications/degrees and define a priority for each between 1-5.

When an applicant is applying for said vacancy he or she will build their CV with predefined categories for skills/qualifications/degrees and they will be able to see their suitability for the position at the bottom of the page in a sort of a progress bar like manner.

How do I go about mapping this logic?

Comment: what is the criteria you want to use  skill or qualification or degree  or all of these three?

Comment: @HassanTariq it depends on the vacancy requirement, doesn't really matter. What matters is the priority that the HR exec gives to whatever the requirement may be... That's how I thought about going about it, by prioritizing the requirement between 1 and 5, it narrows down the logic mapping part, I'm still unclear about it however.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific method by which you can achieve this you have to do this by some backend logic i means there is no builtin method in angular js for this problem you have implement some search and sorting alogrithims

Comment: It has nothing to do angularjs functionality. Its a certain mathematical formula or research that will help me solve the problem specified. Perhaps I should post it on math.stackexchange. Thanks for taking the time.